# Pros and cons of Monero's potential Seraphis Protocol Upgrade

Tags: protocol

Seraphis is an up and coming potential upgrade for Monero, but what are some of the major and minor pros and cons of this upgrade?

The only ones I know of are being able to create a view wallet where one can see incoming and outgoing transactions, a big deal imo. The new address format might prove problematic, but what are the proposed solutions to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following assumes the Seraphis upgrade is accompanied by the Jamtis addressing scheme.

Pros:

- Massive improvement in ring size (privacy improvement).
- Increased modularity of transaction protocol (easier upgrades in the future).
- New wallet tier allowing full view-only wallet functionality without spend key. <sup>1</sup>
- New wallet tier allowing fast light wallet syncing with greater privacy than existing solutions.<sup>1</sup>
- New address scheme adds first-class support for embedded signatures to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks.<sup>1</sup>
- <s>Wallets will synchronize much faster thanks to view tags and other performance enhancements.</s>
- New seed format (Polyseed) will be 16 words and will embed the wallet restore height, streamlining user experience.<sup>2</sup>

Cons:

- New wallet tiers add complexity.<sup>1</sup>
- Users will need to generate new addresses.
- New addresses are longer.<sup>1</sup>
- Transactions will be slightly larger.
- New seed format may confuse users restoring older seeds (however, older seeds **will still work**). <sup>2</sup>

Overall, it is very clear to me that this is a massive step forwards for Monero and its users. Better privacy, better performance, and a better user experience after the dust has settled.

Edit: I have been corrected, view tags are not part of Seraphis. They will be implemented sooner.

<sup>1</sup> Specific to Jamtis, not necessarily Saraphis.

<sup>2</sup> Not specific to Jamtis or Seraphis, but will likely gain traction as part of the same update.

Comment: whats a rough estimate of when this might get implemented?

Comment: "view tags" are nothing to do with Seraphis. Neither is the new seed format really.

Comment: Oh good catch on the view tags, thank you, I corrected it. I mention the seed format because it's lumped in with Jamtis in the Jamtis gist, so I think it fits as part of the overall upgrade.

Comment: @BusyBoredom the proposed *address scheme* (Jamtis) is not part of Seraphis. Sure, Seraphis makes new wallet types (tiers) possible (and *requires* a new address scheme), but Jamtis (the address scheme), whilst devised with Seraphis in mind, could be applied to some other protocol. In addition, Polyseed (the seed format/encoding I refer to) is again separate from Seraohis *and* Jamtis; it could be used right now if we wanted.

Comment: Fair enough @jtgrassie. I was lumping them together because from a user's perspective they're part of the same update, but I will edit my post to clarify.

Comment: @BusyBoredom "because from a user's perspective they're part of the same update" they're not though. Polyseed (and view-tags) do *not* need to come in the same update as Seraphis. Neither does Jamtis really.

Comment: I understand they are only happening at the same time because Seraphis needs a new addressing scheme anyway. I apologize for associating them too strongly, I was trying to simplify my answer and I see that I simplified too much. Is my most recent edit sufficient in your eyes?